# Python Tkinter - How do I change variables from outside the main window class?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Now i understand the concept of instance variables and classes, I've never had a problem with them before and I use them frequently. However when I make my MainWindow class, everything is peachy until i try accessing instance variables.

http://pastebin.com/tDs5EJhi is the full code, but at this point it's just placing labels and frames and whatnot, no actual logic is going on. The window looks fine and nothing bad happens.

My question comes to be when I try changing things inside of the window externally. I figured I could just make an instance of the class and change variables from there (namely instancevariable.ImageCanvas.itemconfig()) like i can normally, but Tkinter isn't being nice about it and I think it's a result of Tkinter's mainloop().

Here's the tidbit of my class MainWindow() that i'm having trouble with (ln 207)

```
            ...
            self.C4 = Tk.PhotoImage(file="temp.png")
            self.card4 = self.CardCanvas.create_image(120,46,image=self.C4, state=Tk.NORMAL)
            #self.CardCanvas.itemconfig(4, state=Tk.HIDDEN) # < It works here
            ...
        self.root.mainloop()

window = MainWindow()
window.CardCanvas.itemconfig(4, state=Tk.HIDDEN) # < It doesn't work here
```

That's how i learned how to edit instance variables. When the window pops up, the itemconfig command doesn't actually apply like it would were it inside the class (or maybe it did and the window just didn't update?) and after closing the window I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name
```

which I assume is just because it's trying to apply a method to variables that don't exist anymore, now that the window has closed.

So I guess here's my big question - I have a MainWindow class, and from what I can tell, nothing can be changed from outside of the class because the Tk.mainloop() is running and won't stop to let other code after it run, like the itemconfig. How do I go about changing those variables? Code after the instance variable declaration doesn't seem to run until the MainWindow() is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that code after `mainloop` doesn't run. It does, but only after the GUI has been destroyed. Tkinter is designed for the call to `mainloop` be the last (or very nearly last) line of executable code. Once it is called, all other work must be done as reaction to events. That is the essence of GUI programming.

The answer to "how do I go about changing the variables" is simple: do it before you call `mainloop`, or do it in reaction to an event. For example, do it in a callback to a button, do it in a function bound to an event, or to a time-based event via `after`, and so on.

Comment: I think 'after' is what I'm looking for in regards to updating the window. Thanks for the help!